# POSTGRESQL | EDITAR BASE DE DATOS

Tags: postgresql

Les cuento:

PROBLEMA: Necesito cambiar manualmente el valor de 3 celdas puntuales en una columna

LO QUE INTENTÉ: Modificarlas manualmente, con la interfaz de PgAdmin (primera foto), pero me pide guardar las modificaciones y no sé cómo hacer eso (segunda foto).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De antemano, gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arreglé con 'update' y 'set'

update referencia set id_referencia = '3'
where id_referencia = '8'